# Critique my algorithm for measuring similar/difference of groups using multiple variables

Tags: python, clustering, distance, multivariate-distribution

So I've been trying to solve a problem of quantitatively measuring the similarity/difference between groups in my dataset. I am not trying to cluster data to create groups, because the groups are political divisions. I am trying to quantify how similar respective groups are. Here's my thought process:

For each group, calculate a centroid using the n dimensions.

Calculate the Euclidean distances between each point.

So in this 3 dimensional example, if the centroids are at:

| Group | Coordinates of Centroid |
| --- | --- |
| A | (1,1,1) |
| B | (2,1,1) |
| C | (10,10,10) |

Then the distances would be:

| x | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 0 | 1 | 15.59 |
| b | 1 | 0 | 15.03 |
| c | 15.59 | 15.03 | 15.59 |

Any critiques or feedback would be very appreciated.

Comment: Find centroid using median. It is robust to outliers.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @amolgoel